# Need to load a specific css pending on the passed parameter

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the example from [Dynamic CSS using Razor Engine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/171695/Dynamic-CSS-using-Razor-Engine) and I have the following:

This is in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<link href="@Url.Action("Index", "Css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is my CssController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RazorEngine;

namespace SuburbanCustPortal.Controllers
{
    public class CssController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Css/

        public string Index(string id)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("id: " + id);
          Response.ContentType = "text/css";
          return Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Content/Site.css")));
        }

    }
}
```

Where my issue is, I need to load a specific CSS file pending on the guid (id) that is passed in when they first visit the site. The id from the index above is coming out as null but it is loading.

example:

> mysite.com/account/login/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/

I need to load the css based on that guid.

Is it possible to grab that value from the _Layout.cshtml or is there another way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that Guid in session:

Account Controller:

```
public ActionResult LogIn(Guid identifier)
{
     Session["Identifier"] = identifier;
     return View();
}
```

In layout:

```
<link href="@Url.Action("Index", "Css", new { id = Session["Identifier"] })" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Css Controller:

```
public string Index(Guid id)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("id: " + id);
      Response.ContentType = "text/css";
      return Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Content/Site.css")));
    }
```

You can change session variable any time from any controller